# Oracle Bind Variable giving error

Tags: oracle, oracle10g, ora-01400

```
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON

VARIABLE dept_id NUMBER

DECLARE

  max_deptno NUMBER(3);

  dept_name departments.department_name%TYPE :='Education';

BEGIN

  SELECT MAX(department_id)

  INTO max_deptno 

  FROM departments;

  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ('The maximum department no is : '  || max_deptno);

  :dept_id:=(max_deptno+10);

  INSERT INTO departments (department_name, department_id,location_id)

  VALUES(dept_name,  :dept_id, NULL);

  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ('The number of rows affected : '  || SQL%ROWCOUNT);


END;

/
```

Error report:
ORA-01400: cannot insert NULL into ("SYSTEM"."DEPARTMENTS"."DEPARTMENT_ID")
ORA-06512: at line 10
01400. 00000 -  "cannot insert NULL into (%s)"
*Cause:
*Action:
The maximum department no is : 190

I am getting this error while trying to execute the bind variable in oracle statment. But if i put some value instead of bind variable, i get this insert statement right. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: are you not inserting null in  a numeric field.?

Comment: no the bind variable(:dept_id) is giving me problem. INSERT INTO departments (department_name, department_id,location_id)
  VALUES('jim',  200, NULL); works fine...

Comment: Add the following for troubleshooting: DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ('The department id is : ' || dept_id);

Comment: My bad. :dept_id:=(max_deptno+10) should just be dept_id = (max_deptno+10). The prefixing of colon is not needed while variable declaration.

Comment: @doc_180 : it gives me the error; Error report:
ORA-06550: line 9, column 11:
PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "=" when expecting one of the following:

   := . ( @ % ;
ORA-06550: line 10, column 3:
PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "DBMS_OUTPUT" 
ORA-06550: line 10, column 62:
PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol ";" when expecting one of the following:

   . ( , * % & - + / at mod remainder rem <an identifier>
   <a double-quoted delimited-identifier> <an exponent (**)> as
   from into || multiset bulk
06550. 00000 -  "line %s, column %s:\n%s"

Comment: sql_stmt := 'INSERT INTO departments (department_name, department_id,location_id)
VALUES(:1, :2, :3);';
  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE sql_stmt USING department_name, department_id, NULL;

Comment: @doc_180 : Error report:
ORA-06550: line 14, column 63:
PLS-00457: expressions have to be of SQL types
ORA-06550: line 14, column 3:
PL/SQL: Statement ignored
06550. 00000 -  "line %s, column %s:\n%s"
*Cause:    Usually a PL/SQL compilation error.
*Action:

Comment: Instead of NULL could you pass another variable for location id. I loggin off, so gd luck

Comment: @doc_180 : If i put, INSERT INTO departments (department_name,department_id,location_id) VALUES(dept_name,200,NULL); It will work. But when i use the bind variable in the place of 200, it gives me error.

Comment: Is there any particular reason why you're using a SQL*Plus VARIABLE?

Comment: @Jeffrey Kemp: Yes i have to use bind variable unfortunately, its part of an assignment :(.

Comment: @need_the_buzz: You don't need VARIABLE for bind variables to be used. For example, in your code, `dept_name` is a bind variable in the INSERT statement.

Answer (score 1):

I think the value of the bind variable is only set when the pl/sql block is finished. And it probably has to terminate normally.

One solution is to use `max_deptno+10` in the insert insead of `:dept_if`. A better solution is to create another pl/sql variable and use that in the insert statement.

```
new_dept_id := max_deptno+10;
:dept_id := new_dept_id;
```

You also have to change the INSERT statement:

```
INSERT INTO departments (department_name,department_id,location_id)
    VALUES(dept_name, new_dept_id, NULL);
```

Comment: As you said i have changed the query like this `SET SERVEROUTPUT ON VARIABLE dept_id NUMBER DECLARE max_deptno NUMBER(3); dept_name departments.department_name%TYPE :='Education'; sql_stmt varchar2(100); new_dept_id NUMBER(3); BEGIN SELECT MAX(department_id) INTO max_deptno FROM departments; new_dept_id := max_deptno+10; DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ('added : ' || new_dept_id); :dept_id := new_dept_id; INSERT INTO departments (department_name,department_id,location_id) VALUES(dept_name,:dept_id,NULL); END;` /...............But still error

Comment: You also have the change the VALUES list in the INSERT statement. That's why I suggested a new variable. The bind variable is only set when the block terminates. I modified my answer to add the INSERT statement.

Answer (score 0):

I think this error is obtained because you use bind variable without using `set autoprint on` in start program.